# how to list all available slots in vue component

Tags: vue.js

I'm working on tool for design system and manual isolated testing of Vue components.

I would like to list all available slots and scopedSlots without rendering a component in DOM. Ideally - to do it on client side, but also possible on server-side (using vue test utils or whatever that works).

I tried to access slots from `vm` but `vm.$slots` has only slots that filled from parent component.

Is there a way to get list of all slots somehow? I would like to avoid writing our own parser for templates...

Comment: UPD: I could use vue-template-compiler and check AST for tags "slot". But is there a better option?

Answer (score -1):

I guess it's only possible on mounted. You can use $refs for this: `this.$refs['your-ref'].$slots` and `this.$refs['your-ref'].$scopedSlots`

Comment: $slots and $scopedSlots only list slots filled when using the component. :-(  It's actually a bit confusing since their contents can change at runtime if you have a v-if in your template.