# Get list of slot names from Vue template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm creating an interactive style guide for some custom components we've created at my job. It goes through the list of globally registered components and then displays their props. The user can then edit the prop values and see how it affects the rendered component.

Right now I need to figure out how to allow interaction with slots for certain components we have. For example, we have our own `button` component that looks something like this:

```html
<template>
    <button :class="customClasses">
        <slot></slot>
    </button>
</template>
```

I have a `componentPreviewRenderer` component that shows a rendering of our custom components. It looks something like this:

```js
export default {
    props: {
        component: String, //The name of the global component to render
        props: Object //List of component props
    },
    render (createElement): {
        return createElement(
            this.component,
            {
                props: this.props
            }
        );
    }
}
```

I need to (1) find out if the component's template I'm rendering has slots and (2) get a list of the slot names so I can pass it into the `createElement()` function and let the user edit the slot values. For example, for the button component they should be able to edit the "default" slot which controls the text appearing on the button.

I've already looked at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50545561/how-to-list-all-available-slots-in-vue-component) but I'd like to be able to get the slot names directly from the Vue component I'm rendering instead of having to parse through the .vue file. I tried things like `Vue.component(this.component).$slots` but  `$slots` is undefined. Does anyone know how I would get the slot names for the component being rendered?